# When has a human-based service replaced an automated one?

Tags: automation

I'm looking for examples where a human-based service replaced an automated one. For example, machine translation (although suboptimal in quality) largely replaced human translation in many areas -- can anyone think of where the opposite has occurred (especially with regard to today's industry)?

**Edit:** Before you downvote because this doesn't have the keyword C++, my reasoning is that programmers invariably create these technologies, and programmers are the ones who are either 1) displaced by the revival of human service, or 2) asked to somehow integrate the human element in a service. When there are questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895296/how-can-you-tell-if-a-person-is-a-programmer), it doesn't make sense to downvote this (unless you downvoted that, too).

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to the art of programming. Sounds like more of a history-of-technology question.

Comment: =/ I actually liked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.com) is, I think, a direct counter-example to your machine translation example (since it's a form of visual translation, so to speak),

perhaps [google image labeller](http://images.google.com/imagelabeler/) counts

I recall something about yahoo running a "humans do simple tasks online for you cheaply, in the place of cpu cycles" scheme.

Crowdsourcing in general might be something similar to what you're thinking of.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of Amazon.com's Mechanical Turk (named after a device that purported to play chess, but really had a human inside manipulating it).

Comment: These are great examples! Exactly what my question was looking for.

Comment: Right, mechanical turk was/is what I was recalling.
https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most exciting examples, but certainly among the most common--used everyday by pretty much everyone. Non-trivial as well.

1. **Electronic Stability Control** (braking-steering control in many (most?) automobiles
2. **Auto-focus** in some digital cameras.

Comment: aren't those examples of a computer replacing a human? The question was for the other way around.

Comment: Well the digital camera example is interesting.  Sure, the typical user uses auto-focus.  However, when it comes to professional photography, there simply is no replacement to manually making sure everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

It is an unlikely situation because for a machine to have been given the responsibility in the first place you would expect it to have been sufficiently good/cheap/etc at the task. So for it to then be replaced by a human, the human approach would need to have some how got better or cheaper at a faster rate than the technology driven one.

That's not to say that there isn't an example of this of course. I think it is an interesting question.

Comment: Very true. Interesting to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard there are CAPTCHA-resolving centers in India. That may be a lie though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have an interesting example of this.

A few years ago I was working for a company writing a Dive School System for a Hotel in Sharm El Sheikh (in Egypt) along with a new "front of house" system. We were trying to come up with a fast check-in system for checking in an entire busload of divers arriving from the airport, the thing is, in Egypt labor is very very cheap, and the end it was more costly to do this with a computer system, than to continue with the old manual system of simply having 15-20 staff doing the checking in.

Comment: Unfortunately, that should not be only about cost. The fast check-in system could (if it worked) also provide something more efficient (read: speedy).

Comment: nah, thats the point, it was faster (for the customer) with the bulk staff, and that was the overriding concern (not the cost) i.e  customer satisfaction.

Comment: In this case, everyone should be happy ...